# Disable "square bracket to array" parsing of form value names

Tags: php, forms

As you know, if you have a form containing

```
<select name="user">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="user[name]" />
<input type="password" name="user[password]" />
```

And you submit that form, in PHP, `$_REQUEST['user']` will automatically become an array containing the keys `name` and `password`, and the value of the select will be gone. The opposite occurs if the `<select>` is moved after the other two fields. `$_REQUEST['user']` will contain the value of the select, and the values in the inputs will be gone, with nothing being set to either `$_REQUEST['user[name]']` or `$_REQUEST['user[password]']`.

To my knowledge, the same applies to `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_FILES`.

Also, input streams are unavailable when the form's MIME is `multipart/form-data`.

So, is there any way to disable this automatic parsing?

Comment: I am not sure this can be done but you may find using $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA useful

Comment: @mmonem still unavailable on `multipart/form-data` and it's actually worse than input streams.

Comment: I'll try to look at the php sources

Comment: I checked the latest source of PHP (version 5.6 as of 20 June 2014) and I can't find a way to disable this features

Comment: I think you're chasing the wrong solution. The correct solution is to stop overriding your form names (i.e. _rename the `select`_).

Comment: @mmonem you should turn that comment into an answer saying "there's no way to do it", so I can accept it. The other answer suggests a completely alternate approach which is not relevant to the original question.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL: Don't be rude. The answer is quite correct, providing a meaningful and workable solution that is _the right thing to do here_. If you want a pointless "no" answer then, fine, here's one. Hope that helps... o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the answer unfortunately doesn't handle cases that are outside my control, my friend. I'm not even trying to be a jerk, it's just the way it is. I commented in danjfoley's answer that an alternate approach won't suffice. Sorry there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do it as of version 5.6 main development branch at 20 June 2014

Comment: Added the answer as per **client** request :)

Answer (score 3):

A. change

```
<select name="user">
```

to

```
<select name="user[user]">
```

That way you have a key set for the user array. If you are going to use post arrays you have to make sure every single one has a key.

B. (the way i'd do it)

Forget about the arrays. Use a unique name for each one. Using the arrays give you no benefit. Call the first one user, the second one, user_name, and the 3rd "password"

Comment: I agree with all of this except the very last bit: if you have `user_name` and `password`, then what does `user` mean? Call it something else.

Comment: Agreed. Just called it that because that is what i saw i the quesrion

Comment: This is from a forms builder that can merge fields from one form to another. I don't believe there's an easy way to warn the user about collisions, but the easiest way I've found is to change square brackets to something else, and put them back on the server.  It's not what I asked for though. I asked if there's away to disable PHP's behavior, so the answer, I'm afraid, is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I wish there was a way to disable PHP's arrayification of query parameter names, but I don't think there is. What you *can* do (except with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`) is parse the query yourself using something like:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $qs = file_get_contents ('php://input');
} else {
  $qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}

if ($qs !== '') {
  $params = explode ('&', $qs);

  foreach ($params as $p) {
    $nv = explode ('=', $p, 2);
    $name = urldecode ($nv[0]);
    $value = urldecode ($nv[1]);
    echo htmlspecialchars ($name), ': "', htmlspecialchars ($value), "\"\n";
  }
}
```

This also gets around PHP's annoying habit of replacing "illegal" characters in query parameter names, such as dots with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it is not possible.**

If you don't want form arrays, don't use form arrays. Call your inputs something else. It's quite simple.

And apparently you are not interested in workable, conventional and meaningful solutions to your problem.

Comment: Please see my comment on danjfoley's answer.